# Software tool to assist me in documenting a file format

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, documentation-generator, file-format

There's this file format which I want to write some documentation for. It's intended for humans, but should be specific enough so that a person could essentially parse the format (if perhaps slowly) by himself, using this documentation. What I have is:

1. Myself (i.e. this doesn't need to be automated, I need assistance creating/writing the documentation)
2. Some code which currently parses the file whose format I'm documenting

I want something which will make it easier for me to express what-comes-after-what, what-can-fit-in-what-field etc., so that I end up with a semi-graphical layout of what's in the file, or something like a markup which is relatively easy to read etc. I realize this sounds a bit vague, but I can't be quite exactly what I need until I actually start using it.

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Allows saving/exporting in well-known and further-convertible format.

Desired:

- Libre

Notes:

- In my specific case the format is not binary, its text-based, but if you have a more general answer you're welcome. Here's a (slightly obfuscated) snippet:

  ```
  FOO.bar, BAZversion 1234
  8 8 16
  FOOsize=1063
  3 64 system_auth_user 3 0 1 256 0 str 1 1 1409 0 0 0 0 0 1 256 0 8208 10240 0
  4 64 system_auth_passwd_v2 4 0 1 256 0 str 1 1 1409 0 0 0 0 0 1 256 0 8332 10240 0
  48 32 snapshots_bid 60 0 0 256 0 int 4 0 1409 0 0 0 0 0 0 1024 0
  ```
- It can be web-based, I don't care.
- It can be a combination of software tools or a piece of software + method of using it

Comment: Are we talking about a byte byte layout? or at least "section A begins at offest X, and the first two bytes are its length. Section B follows the end of section A ...."   Could you give a small example? I am interested in this question

Comment: @Mawg: No, not a byte-by-byte layout since it's a textual format. I'll link to a small example.

Comment: Can you code? Would you be willing to code a parser for others to use? If so, you can't really beat [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/), especially if you use the visual ANTLR workbench and plugins for Eclipse, NetBeans, etc

Comment: @Mawg: There already is a parser in existence. But there's no documentation for people who want to understand the format in context of other aspects of the software system using it. I want to write that documentation. Would Antlr really help me with that?

Comment: Probably not :-(   But, keep it in mind next time you need a parser. remember the first time you discovered Lex/Yacc and thought "wow! I'll never hand craft another parser again"? Try ANTLR and "wow, I'll never use Lex/Yacc, or even Flex/Bison, again"

Comment: @Mawg: If I wanted to write a parser, I'd use boost::spirit::x3 of course, not that silly Java stuff. And if someone forced my hand to go C-only I'd use Lemon.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to two new tools, which I will immediately check out. "that silly Java stuff" ... I don't code it myself, but certainly wouldn't refuse to use a program coded in it

Comment: Can you explain why Lemon is better than/different from Lex/Yacc?  boost::spirit::x3 just looks like regexp - did I miss something? Please do try Antlr with work bench; it lets you visually step your grammar as it parses, one character at a time, pushing & popping tokens and completing expressions. There isn't anything to compare, not even Sandstone Visual Parse++, if that is still around,  and that used to cost about $400, were Antlr is free

Comment: Boost Spirit X3 is not about regexps - it's a powerful parser which, after compilation, should be very fast. It also makes it so that the formal specification of the grammar to be parsed is done in a way that's both relatively intuitive and at the same time valid C++ code. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSBWklPLRvw). But we're going off-topic here. Oh, and about Lemon: [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_Parser_Generator).